# Is there a way to use OffScreen Rendering in CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I want to use OffScreen Rendering in `CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser`. Should it be rewritten to `CefSharp.OffScreen.ChromiumWebBrowser`?

The main idea is to preload a web page and show it on the WinForms window. Currently in my solution it takes a few seconds to fully render the web page on the window.
I want the logic - when I load the new url, the previous one should be visible on the screen, then, after some time (5 seconds) I want to show the newly loaded url, which was rendering during that 5 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no out of the box solution for using `OffScreen Rendering` in `WinForms`. You would need to implement that yourself. It's no small task and I'd suggest looking for alternate solutions before undertaking that task.

You can call [Control.CreateControl()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.createcontrol?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) in `WinForms` to force the creation of a `ChromiumWebBrowser` instance.

```cs
chromiumWebBrowser.CreateControl();
```

You could for instance create a `ChromiumWebBrowser` in the background and then replace the existing instance when loaded.

Further reading at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1406#issuecomment-616226653